# how to kill a Genymotion VM via command prompt?

Tags: android, shell, android-virtual-device, genymotion

The command

> player --vm-name VM_NAME

is for launching a Genymotion VM and

What is the command for kill a Genymotion VM?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Just press `x`

Comment: @jyoon I want to write a script to test android and want to launch and clear environment (kill genymotion vm) automatically via command line

Comment: @jyoonPro pressing the X does not work because the process continues to work (MacOs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `kill` command on *nix like systems and `taskkill` in Win systems.

A nice post on using Genymotion in a Jenkins setup is available at http://krazyrobot.com/2014/05/calabash-genymotion-and-jenkins/. An excerpt of the command is below:

```
PID=`ps | grep "Genymotion\.app/Contents/MacOS/player.*7b4f5185-b7d6-4151-9b09-9cefba4c0967.*" | awk '{print $1}'`
kill $PID
```

Answer (score 2):

If you simply run the same command with -x it will close the box

```
player --vm-name VM_NAME -x
```

Taken from the help I managed to find in the logs

```
[debug] Usage: player
[debug]          --vm-name|-n <device name>
[debug]          [ --no-popup|-s ]
[debug]          [ --poweroff|-x  || 
[debug]            --startadb|-a  || 
[debug]            --stopadb|-z ]
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, this oneliner should work with all versions of Genymotion on Mac OSX:

```
ps x | grep "Genymotion\.app/Contents/MacOS/.*player" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill
```

The Genymotion player path for prior versions was:

```
Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/player
```

The Genymotion player path for v2.6.0 is:

```
Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/Player.app/Contents/MacOS/player
```

But if you shut it down by force like this way, sometimes later if you try to restore the snapshot, you may fail due to **`VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE`**

```
VBoxManage: error: Cannot delete the current state of the running machine (machine state: Running)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE (0x80bb0002), component SessionMachine, interface IMachine, callee nsISupports
```

Solution - shut down the VM gracefully before killing Genymotion player:

```
vboxmanage controlvm $YOUR_VM_NAME poweroff || true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **DISCARD** the state of VirtualBox Machine directly, you can type in terminal:

```
vboxmanage discardstate 'My Genymotion name machine'
```